# Why can't I remove a reference from an Access 2010 .accdb project?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Experimenting with shared modules in MS Access 2010, I want to remove a reference to a compiled database (.accde) containing the code module, but the 'remove' option is greyed out for both the module and the containing database in the project browser.  How can I drop the reference?  The code is in design mode, not debug.

Apologies if this should be obvious.

Comment: That is the main advantage (in your case disadvantage) of compiling a file to executable only. As no design changes can be made once it is compiled. I do not think even VBA can help in dropping reference once it is compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove referenced library-databases from within the Project Explorer.

Use the References-Dialog in the **menu** "Tools"-"References" within the VBA-Editor to remove the reference.

Comment: Thanks; I was correct - it should have been obvious really.